# Wordpress rewrite url help needed

Tags: posts, permalinks

I am using wordpress and very new in wordpress. 
I need url rewrite method, i guess it doesnot changes in permalinks.
 I need to work on .htacess file. I am adding locations where i have to add LokId, Now my url is  like this.

```
 www.url.com/locations/titlename/.
```

What Actual I want url like this.

> www.url.com/locations/lok id(act city name)/titlename/.

Do i need to do work on .htacess file. 
Please give me idea how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the permalink properties in www.url.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php, without editing your .htaccess file.

You can choose the last option and add there the "city name" you need.